# How to stop the screen rotation in android?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-manifest, screen-rotation

I want to prevent my app from the rotation, but I don't want to specify the screen Orientation in every activity tag in the manifest file instead I want to define it only once in my application which should work for the whole app.
Is there any way to do that?
Or I need to specify this in every activity?

Comment: Ideally, you have very few activities. Use fragments or composables to define your screens.

Comment: No actually I have more then 15 screen and I am using activity and not using compose

Comment: Having that many activities is not recommended in modern Android app development.

Comment: Will remember that definitely but is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

there is a way, you can create baseActivity and make all activities extend it.

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
    }
}

class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {
   
}
```